# How to change variable when i press button in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I change some variable at view by pressing button using Angular?

For example view:

```
<div id="someDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-bind="firstname"></p>
  <button type="button" ng-click="changeValue('Joe')"></button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.firstname = "Johny";

        $scope.changeValue= function(param) {  
        $scope.firstname = param;
        }
        });
```

I expect when I'll press button then instead Johny will be Joe (as in parameter).
At the moment when i click on the button nothing happens

---

**@EDIT**
Ok i know where is the problem. This works fine at my main div. However it doesn't work on my second div:

I run script below by clicking other button, and this script changed my div

```
 function show(div_id){ //div_id is `someDiv`
        document.getElementById('main_place').innerHTML = document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML; 
        }
```

But why angular script doesn't work on this div?

Comment: You are calling "changeValue" from your view , but the function name in the controller is "hidePrefs" . Is this how you are doing or is it a typo?

Comment: Just typo, edited already.

Comment: your code is work correctly. try test it when edited typo mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that one.

HTML:

```
<div id="someDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-bind="firstname"></p>
  <button type="button" ng-click="changeValue('Joe')"></button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.firstname = "Johny";

  $scope.changeValue= function(param) {  
    $scope.firstname = param;
  }
});
```

I created working example with your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$scope.changeValue = function(newVal) {
   $scope.firstname = newVal;
}
```

And on html put `<p>{{firstname}}<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in controller:

```
$scope.changeValue = function(changeName)
{
$scope.firstname = changeName;
};
```

In View:

```
<p>{{firstname}}</p>
```

Comment: why use braket and ng-bind in same time?

Comment: Well still doesn't work, furthermore without `ng-bind` i can't see even default: `Johny`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.firstname = "Johny";
    $scope.changeValue = function(param) {  
        $scope.firstname = param;
    }
});

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="someDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="firstname"></p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changeValue('Joe')">Click</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/dz553Og6E83wx0LF6NHT?p=preview